# MVC to redirect with route values instead of query string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing, query-string

I am working on a sample application where I have a register and detail actions.
I want to redirect to the detail view after I registered a new team.

My Regsiter post code looks like this;

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(TeamEditorVm teamRegisterVm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var teamDetailVm = await Managers.TeamManager.CreateAsync(teamRegisterVm);
        return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = teamDetailVm.Id });
    }

    return View(teamRegisterVm);
}
```

Is there a way to force `RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = teamDetailVm.Id });` to use route values for the URL like

```
hxxps://test.com/team/detail/1
```

instead of a querystring?

```
hxxps://test.com/team/detail?id=1
```

Comment: It will generate `../team/details/1` if your using the default routing. Show your current route definitions and the signature of the `Details()` method

Comment: Thanks for that idea - I have a catch all route and I added it right before the default route and it is causing it to not recognize that pattern (controller/action/id). I switched it to add the default route first then the "catch all" route and it started working. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = teamDetailVm.Id });
```

This will redirect you to Details action and if your routing contains id as the default parameter, then it will show you

```
hxxps://test.com/team/detail/1
```

and not as query parameter. I just tested it in MVC5 and it was working for me. Please check your routing.

Comment: Turns out that my routes we're added on the wrong order.